# SSL certificate error while attempting to install composer

Tags: php, linux, curl, ssl, composer-php

Every time I try to install Composer with `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`, I get an SSL certificate error, which then asks me to use `-k` which results in nothing happening. Any advice is great.
Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

```
curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls
```

Comment: Thank you very much this took hours to find!

Comment: same here, newbies like me struggle finding up to date SSL certs. thanks!